# Search a value in an object with number keys

Tags: mongodb

In a Mongo collection I have objects like this:

```
{
    "domains" : {
        "0" : "jwlhKRQ",
        "1" : "fgqAvas"
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I select *all documents* that contain a field with value `"jwlhKRQ"` in the `domains` object?

Is this possible with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator, passing to it a javascript function which compares each of the values in `domains` to the given value `"jwlhKRQ"`.

```
db.myCollection.find({ $where:
    function() {
        for (var key in this.domains) {
            if (this.domains[key] == "jwlhKRQ") {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Note this kind of query cannot take advantage of indexes.

Comment: Is there any other solution without using a function?

Comment: Not that I know of, unless re-structuring the data is an option. If you can store the data as `{domains: ["jwlhKRQ", "fgqAvas"]}`, then you can use the `$in` operator.